# NServiceBus ServiceInsight, couldnt see message flow

Tags: nservicebus4, serviceinsight

I am using NServiceBus 4.0.3 and I thought of using ServiceInsight, I can see the queues but cant see the workflow. Not sure if I need to configure anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceInsight works in two modes, one is using Queue Explorer and working with queues the other one is Endpoint Explorer which uses Management API (a.k.a Service Control) to retreive the data and operate on messages. Each come with their pros and cons:

Queue Explorer

- Can connect to MSMQ
- Provides message information, body, header
- Allows returning the message to the source (in case of errors)
- Allows you to see the exception if there is one associated with the message.
- You need to have MSMQ installed locally and setup the permissions properly to connect to a remove queue. At this stage it is more for connecting to the local dev machine.

Endpoint Explorer

- All of what queue explorer provides
- Is more transport agnostic. Can/Will work with whatever transport type you have chosen.
- Displays Message Flow which is a conceptual overview of what type of messages are sent across endpoints

To see the flow diagram, you need to connect to Management API/Service Control which (if you have used installer) usually runs on your localhost the port you have specified. See my [blog post](http://www.hightech.ir/SeeSharp/serviceinsight-for-nservicebus-beta-two-available-now) for more info.